# How do i set up a simple IVR

Tags: twilio

Help please...

I just want to set up an IVR on Twilio that takes a call and asks for a response on the keypad of 1 or 2 and then redirects to a telephone number. How do I approach this as I have no idea?

Is this simple?

Thanks

Barry -

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very simple. Follow this YouTube video to get started using Twilio Studio.

[How To Build an IVR System with Twilio Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GifYSpB-EU4)

[Getting Started with Twilio Studio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015961327-Getting-Started-with-Twilio-Studio)